# Decide wordpress navigation hover color with css of .current-menu-item

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, hover

In the standard navigation of Wordpress I would like to change the hover colors of the links depending on the page that is active at that specific moment.

Because every single page has a different `:active` color,  the hover color also needs to change to the same color of the active link.

In Wordpress the active element gets a class which is called: `.current-menu-item`

I've tried using the wordpress codex, but nothing is as similar as this situation.

Because the color needs to be dynamic I think the solution needs to be done with help of Jquery or something similar?

Comment: You could add a `Custom field` for each post, with the colour value - http://krogsgard.com/2012/wordpress-body-class-post-meta/

Comment: But do I need to give every single page a different meta now?